# iText 7: How to build a paragraph mixing different fonts?

Tags: itext, itext7

I've been using iText 7 for a few days to build pdf files, unfortunately, iText 7 is very different from iText 5 and the documentation is still very incomplete.

I'm trying to build a paragraph that mixes two fonts or two fonts style (example: have a bold text in the middle of a paragraph)

Using iText 5 this would be done using Chunks:

```
Font regular = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12);
Font bold = Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD);
Phrase p = new Phrase("NAME: ", bold);
p.add(new Chunk(cc_cust_dob, regular));
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(p);
```

Using iText 7, I still haven't found way to do this.

Has anyone tried to do this using the last version of iText?

Note: I'm using the csharp but java is also useful

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please read the documentation, more specifically [iText 7: building blocks "Chapter 1: Introducing the PdfFont class"](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-1-introducing-pdffont-class)

In that chapter, you'll discover that it's much easier to switch fonts when using iText 7, because you can work with default fonts and font sizes, you can define and reuse `Style` objects, and so on.

An example:

```
Style normal = new Style();
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
normal.setFont(font).setFontSize(14);
Style code = new Style();
PdfFont monospace = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.COURIER);
code.setFont(monospace).setFontColor(Color.RED)
    .setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add(new Text("The Strange Case of ").addStyle(normal));
p.add(new Text("Dr. Jekyll").addStyle(code));
p.add(new Text(" and ").addStyle(normal));
p.add(new Text("Mr. Hyde").addStyle(code));
p.add(new Text(".").addStyle(normal));
document.add(p);
```

First we define a `Style` that we call `normal` and that uses 14 pt Times-Roman. Then we define a `Style` that we call `code` and that uses 12 pt Courier in Red with a gray background.

Then we compose a `Paragraph` using `Text` objects that use these styles.

Note that you can chain `add()` comments, as is done in this example:

```
Text title1 = new Text("The Strange Case of ").setFontSize(12);
Text title2 = new Text("Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde").setFontSize(16);
Text author = new Text("Robert Louis Stevenson");
Paragraph p = new Paragraph().setFontSize(8)
    .add(title1).add(title2).add(" by ").add(author);
document.add(p);
```

We set the font size of the newly created `Paragraph` to 8 pt. This font size will be inherited by all the objects that are added to the `Paragraph`, unless the objects override that default size. This is the case for `title1` for which we defined a font size of 12 pt and for `title2` for which we defined a font size of 16 pt. The content added as a `String` (`" by "`) and the content added as a `Text` object for which no font size was defined inherit the font size 8 pt from the `Paragraph` to which they are added.

This is a copy/paste from the official tutorial. I hope this is sufficient for StackOverflow where "link-only" answers aren't allowed. This "no link-only answers rule" shouldn't lead to copy/pasting a full chapter of a manual...

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for the information.

I was looking for this information on the site and I was not able to find it, where is the entry point on the site? 

(besides clicking on the link that you have posted)

The tutorial on the site points me to: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial

Comment: A site update broke links into the iText site. For those looking for the link referenced in the post in the future: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-java/chapter-1-introducing-basic-building-blocks